# How to install new Recovery image from .img file

Tags: htc-evo, installation, clockworkmod-recovery, recovery-mode

I recently found that I could upgrade to the new CWM touch recovery version for my EVO 4g! However, to do this through the ROM manager app or get it directly onto the phone at all, it required a payment, although they specified it could be found (the same version) for free on their website. So naturally, I went and downloaded it as soon as I could.

But instead of a .zip file, as things that I usually flash, it is an .img file. This made sense, since I figured I wouldn't be installing a new recovery through the current recovery version, but I am unknowing as to how to install this new recovery image.

Anyone know what my next step is?

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a fastboot-enabled bootloader version (such as the old 0.76.0000 engineering HBOOT in the EVO's case) you can use that to flash it from a PC via USB. Reboot into your bootloader, then select the "Fastboot" option from the boot menu (if it has one, it may start up fastboot automatically). Once it's ready, go to your PC's shell and execute:

```
fastboot flash recovery /path/to/recovery.img
```

You should also be able to use the `flash_image` binary if your ROM has it ([or you install it from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10630440&postcount=2)). Copy the recovery.img over to your device somewhere then do the following:

```
C:> adb shell
$ su
# flash_image recovery /path/to/recovery.img
```

Comment: used the second method. worked like a charm!! Thanks to both of you

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please

Comment: It depends on your device and the version you're looking for. Team Win Recovery Project has a list on their [devices](https://twrp.me/Devices/) page that can find the .img file for your phone. You can also visit [Clockworkmod](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rb3VzaGlrZHV0dGEucm9tbWFuYWdlciJd), who doesn't seem to provide .img files anymore, but prefers you do it through their app (linked there).

Answer (score 5):

One way is to open ROM Manager and choose "Flash ClockworkMod Recovery".  Select your device when it prompts and wait for it to download the latest (non-touch) recovery.  Using a file browser, go to `/sdcard/clockworkmod/download/<site>/recoveries` and paste your .img there.  `<site>` may be mirror.kanged.net or something else, just check the folders till you find an IMG file with the current date.  Rename the existing .img to something else and rename yours to the exact same name as the existing file was named.  For example, rename `recovery.clockwork-3.0.0.0-evo.img` to `bak.img` and then name your file `recovery.clockwork-3.0.0.0-evo.img`.  Then return to ROM Manager and flash the recovery normally.

Another method is to use fastboot from your PC.  Put your device into fastboot mode and then:

```
fastboot flash recovery <path/to/your-recovery.img>
```

Another is to use a terminal on your device:

```
/data/data/com.koushikdutta.rommanager/files/flash_image <path/to/your-recovery.img>
```

(You can move flash_image somewhere more manageable first, just make sure it has execute permissions.)

Comment: thanks! Edited the question. Which option do i chose in ROM Manager though? Each button to flash a Recovery doesn't let me chose it from my SD card..

Comment: @jlehenbauer I should have added that, it's not exactly straightforward through CWM.  The second and third options are better.

Comment: where do i fine that recovery.img file? Link please