# Restoring LG Optimus 2X P990 back to stock LG software

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-android, restore, lg-optimus-2x

I have flashed a lot of custom ROMs onto my phone, like CM7, kangs and such of CM9 before it's released, MIUI, and so on. I didn't want to wait till the third quarter of 2012 before I got some IC on my phone. Now that we're almost that far into 2012, I was wondering how I could restore my phone back to LG's stock Gingerbread software - the one that i had before I flashed CM7 - and unroot my phone.

I have lost my backup so I cant restore. I'll have to use smart or NVFlash or something like that. How can I restore my LG Optimus 2X P990 back to original LG software, so that I am ready for updating it to LG's ICS release?

Answer (score 2):

There is a zip file that is posted in [this video description](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryGIv8KQVIE) that you can flash via Clockworkmod or your favorite custom recovery that will revert your device completely to stock (including removing the recovery image and such).

The video goes through the process step-by-step, for your convenience, but it's basically flashing that file via CWM, and then being happy :)

*It also goes through how to unroot, if needed!*

Comment: so if i flash the zip file and unroot, i am back into stock, so i can install new updates from lg without problems? It also removed cwm recovery? It says G2X, i have the O2X, will it still work? Or is it two separate files?

Comment: As [this](http://www.phonescoop.com/phones/phone.php?p=3164) site points out, they're the same, one is just the international version and one is not. And yes, the .zip file should remove CWM recovery and unrooting *should* allow you to perform the OTA update.

Comment: But it looks like the interface and launcher, etc is completely different on the g2x, than my o2x was. And i dont want that

Comment: it should all be returned to whatever the stock one was...

Comment: and it should update to ICS soon anyways you said, right? So you'll just have it for a little bit before the update if it turns out to not be what you want.

Comment: So, the ics update for the G2X and the O2X would look the same, so, if i'll restore the one for the G2X, like in the video, it would work, and then i could update it to ics when it comes. (By unrooting it first) I can always just root it and flash back to CM7/CM9 if i dont like it, or if it doesn't work

Comment: Completely true. Backing up first would be advised, or you could do a fresh CM7/9 if you'd like to revert :)

Comment: smooth, i'll download the zip and wait for ics from lg, but you are 100% sure that the G2X version would NOT harm my Optimus 2X P990?

Comment: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sipk4XrN65M) is another video that is specifically for the Optimus 2X, but everywhere I can find the P999 and P990 are referred to as the same device, except one is T-mobile. **I cannot say I am 100% sure this will work** however, as you said, if it fails, restoring to a CM image would not be difficult while we look for other options.

Comment: I'll give it a go, i can live with a non european looking(G2X) until the update comes, because then it will look normal, right?

Comment: Will this also install the lg recovery? It's come to my attention that the T-Mobile G2X and the LG G2X are not the same devices, i THINK, not certain, that the LG G2X has the same layout and stuff as my optimus 2x had

Comment: a crap, bootloops without recovery

Comment: use [the answer to this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21803/how-to-install-new-recovery-image-from-img-file) to install a new recovery, sorry it didn't work! :(

Comment: Fixed it, ended up using SmartFlash to flash stock rom. Got the firmware from XDA

Comment: glad you got it solved!

Comment: Yeah, me too, thanks for the help though:-) Now i'm ready for ics from LG:-) Tried another update from lg, and it worked, so i am sure ics will be updated safely. If ics from LG comes in this century..... lol

Comment: feel free to update my answer with the steps you took, or add your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

I ended up using SmartFlash to flash stock ROM. Got the firmware from XDA.

Links:

SmartFlash tools & drivers: http://android.modaco.com/content/lg-optimus-2x-2x-modaco-com/335494/13-apr-smartflash-stock-baseband-release-1035-21-20110405/

Firmware: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1035041

Steps:

1. Download firmware for your location
2. Download SmartFlash tools and drivers
3. Connect phone to computer on the S/W Upgrade screen - description below
4. Let windows install the drivers
5. Open SmartFlash
6. Go to "Rom copy D/L
7. Select CP bin and AP bin files - description below
8. Make sure "normal mode" is selected
9. Make sure "erase CAL data" is unchecked
10. Make sure channels and such are matching your phone - you'll recognize it
11. Select start and wait till it's completed and your phone will be up and running again with Stock ROM!

CP bin = *.fls file in firmware archive
AP bin = *.bin file in firmware archive

Get into S/W Upgrade screen by pulling your battery out, holding the volume down button and plugging your pc cable in. Hold the volume down until the S/W Upgrade screen appears